# squarespace contact us form fields alignment issue when showing validation message

Tags: squarespace

i am using squarespace tool to create one contact us form my contact form having fields like
first name, last name , email and message

the issue is when i am inserting value for all the fields and except last name fields the validation message taking down the fields to bellow line

any suggession for this issue .
[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUo8q.png)

i have tried to fix this adding custom css and javascript but seems like this is not a good idea to fix this. I need a solution which can resolve it from squrespace end